# How to generate a user role grid

Tags: php, mysql, forms, kohana-3

I have the following tables:

```
       users (id, username, ... )
       roles (id, name)
 roles_users (user_id, role_id)
```

I am wondering how I can create a nice sort of user-role-grid from that which an admin can use to administer roles to users in a clear way. What I would like is basically a table full of checkboxes sort of like this:

```
        Login  Editor  Admin
Alice     ■      ■       ■
Bob       ■      □       □      
Carol     ■      ■       □

                      [Apply]
```

Generating the table isn't too much of a deal, but I am very unsure how to handle it when it comes to how to name all the checkboxes and especially how to read and update the database in a not too clumsy way. Does anyone have any good advice or pointers on how to do this in a mostly clean way?

*I'm using the Kohana 3 framework, if there is anything there that can make this even easier, but I of course welcome any answer.*

Answer (score 0):

I did something similar with Kohana2. Using its models for User and Role, setting the roles for a user was as simple as `$user->roles = $rolesArray`. Then `$user->save()` knew to update/insert automagically.

A way to name the checkboxes is `name="userid[]" value="roleid"`, so `name="1[]" value="2"`. Those will appear as php arrays in the form submission for each userid. Then you can make them into arrays and assign them to each user object.

Comment: Nice. doesn't seem like I can hand an array over to x-to-many relationships in KO3 though.

Comment: Oh, ok. I haven't played with Kohana3 but I assumed that such a nice functionality would have been carried over. You can always delete all roles for that user quickly and then insert the new ones, although that's not very efficient. Or get the existing roles in an array, compare with the new ones (eg `array_diff()`), and delete or insert accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

1. By default `roles` table contains
   both `name` and `description` fields, 
   use it to generate checkboxes.
2. I'd preffer changing permissions for
   one user at once. Something like
   this: 
           `Login      Editor    Admin 
   Alice     ■       □     ■     [Apply]`
3. ORM in Ko3 doesnt support "magic"
   HABTM and provide
   `add()`/`has()`/`remove()` methods to work
   with *Many-to-Many* relations. So, you
   should call remove() first to delete
   old settings (here is my [fix](http://dev.kohanaframework.org/issues/3202) for `remove()`
   method to delete all roles at once), 
   and then call `add()`
   for each new role.  Another way is
   to iterate through the roles and
   check each role with
   `$user->has('role', $role)`.

   Too many queries for me :) You can
   store original user roles and
   calculate diffs (`$removed_roles` and
   `$new_roles`) before saving. Use DB
   Query Builder to delete
   `$removed_roles` and add `$new_roles` (2 queries max).

PS. Yes, my English sucks, I know it ;)